# Confirmation message for anyone

Tags: questions

When I want to confirm some statement, I shall put negative question at the end of the sentence.

> "He is tall, is not he?"

How to phrase this idiom with "anyone"?

> "Anyone can place an order, cannot anyone?"

sounds ugly to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "He is tall, is not he?"

should be:

> "He is tall, isn't he?"

Nobody uses "is not" in this context.

---

> "Anyone can place an order, cannot anyone?"

It sounds (kind of) ugly to me too :)

You can use:

> <strike>Anyone can place an order, isn't it</strike>?

(updated, after nice feedback in the comments. Thank you.)

> Anyone can place an order, isn't that so / right / true?

Or:

> Anyone can place an order, can't they?

Or (to avoid all confusion):

> Anyone can place an order, right?

Comment: Just my opinion: "Anyone can place an order, isn't it?" is not idiomatic, and does not seem correct.  The closest would be "**isn't that true?**", "**isn't that right**", or "**isn't that so?**".

Comment: I agree that *Anyone can place an order, isn't it?* should not be used. It's not a good example of good English.

Comment: Maybe it would work in very informal BrE, as *innit* can be used after pretty much anything. Anyway, *He's tall, is he not?* works as an emphatic option, and the same goes for *Anyone can place an order, can they not?*.